# How do I format my matplotlib graph in this manner?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to visualize some data from a .csv file in a graph with python and matplotlib which I did but I'm not happy with the way it's displayed. It shows the correct value for each sample but with the way it's currently displayed it doesn't look like a proper graph. The X axis is fine, but the values on the Y axis are all over the place. I'd like the Y axis to go from 1 to 7 as well so the line will fluctuate and not go diagonally like it does now. I've looked at the matplotlibs doc but I couldn't find how to do solve this issue.
Here are two images showing the current graph and how I would like it to look.

[image: Current graph]

[image: Graph I want]

And my python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

tijd = []
cpu_waarde = []

with open('proc.csv', newline='') as bestand:
    reader = csv.reader(bestand)
    for row in reader:
        tijd.append(row[0])
        cpu_waarde.append(row[1])
        
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], cpu_waarde)
plt.xlabel('Sample')
plt.ylabel('CPU usage in %')
plt.show()
```

Contents of my csv file (im only using the index [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMYjY.jpg) data of each row:

```
"10/15/2021 10:40:53.626","1.2581289805042612517"
"10/15/2021 10:40:54.644","3.6828169386064337765"
"10/15/2021 10:40:55.668","1.4359127777638913681"
"10/15/2021 10:40:56.699","4.6144989464642600652"
"10/15/2021 10:40:57.716","4.3283546171353615151"
"10/15/2021 10:40:58.733","3.3935498705438420508"
"10/15/2021 10:40:59.750","1.4958186640490056529"
```

Comment: the values that you are plotting cannot possibly appear to fluctuate like you want. They are a straight line how will they display this variance if it is not already in the data? The scale is not the problem. Can you share your data and clarify your question a bit?

Comment: It looks like `matplotlib` is treating the value of `cpu_waarde` as strings and not as floats.  Can you check the that `cpu_waarde` is actually a list of float values?

Comment: Looking at the current graph, is the value on the y-axis a string? Try changing it to numeric format. And I think you can modify the range of the y-axis to `plt.ylim(1,7)`.

Comment: Thank you, yes I didn't realize the float values were given as a string. I fixed the issue by casting it to float.

Comment: Also, note that using pandas, `df = pd.read_csv('proc.csv', columns=['timestamp','CPU usage'])` usually does these conversions automatically.